# How do you programmatically hide a field based on another field on a custom content type?

Tags: theming, nodes

I have built a custom content type that has a boolean field called 'Hide images'. There is also an images field that displays all images at the bottom of the node. I'd like to setup a way so that depending on the 'Hide images' field I can decide whether to display the images field. Is there a way to edit this via a template?

I saw in page--node--contenttype.tpl.php that I could render($page['content']); but I couldn't actually see how I could choose what content to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template, instead of rendering the entire content array, you can break it down to print each individual item separately.  Then, you could wrap the printing of the images in a statement that checks if the boolean value is true/false.

```
<?php if ($content['field_boolean_hide_images'] === FALSE): ?>
  <?php print render($content['field_image']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is just an example and shouldn't be used verbatim.

Also, to create a template for your content type, it would be `node--yourContentType.tpl.php` rather than a page template override.

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. I'm using print <?php render($content['field_image']); ?> Without using an if statement (to test whether I can render it at all) But nothing renders. I have double checked to make sure that is the machine name of my field.

Comment: Are you certain your template file is being used?  Did you forget `print` before `render()`?

Comment: Yes I'm using print. Sorry I omitted that from the comment. I'm certain that the template file is being used because I added junk text as a test and the junk text appears on the page.

Comment: You should install devel and add `dpm($content)` in your template to be sure that you have the render array named correctly.  If `field_image` was correct it would certainly print.  You can also try printing other fields to see if there is an issue with the image field.

Comment: Also, this would be a `node--yourContentType.tpl.php` template, not a page template.

Comment: That was the issue. I had a page--node--contenttype.tpl.php that was styling the entire content type page but not the actual content. Creating a node--contenttype.tpl.php allowed me to edit what was rendered on page--node--contentype when render($page['content']) was called. Thanks!